# How to save form data into 2 data tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to save data from a form into 2 different tables.

**I have this in stripe account controller create:**

```
     def create

            @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
            @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
            @stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id



                  acct = Stripe::Account.create({
                  :country => "US",
                  :type => "custom",
                    legal_entity: {
                      first_name: stripe_account_params[:first_name].capitalize,
                      last_name: stripe_account_params[:last_name].capitalize,
                      type: stripe_account_params[:account_type],
                      dob: {
                        day: stripe_account_params[:dob_day],
                        month: stripe_account_params[:dob_month],
                        year: stripe_account_params[:dob_year]
                      },
                      address: {
                        line1: stripe_account_params[:address_line1],
                        city: stripe_account_params[:address_city],
                        state: stripe_account_params[:address_state],
                        postal_code: stripe_account_params[:address_postal]
                      },
                      ssn_last_4: stripe_account_params[:ssn_last_4]
                    },
                    tos_acceptance: {
                      date: Time.now.to_i,
                      ip: request.remote_ip
                    }

            })

            @stripe_account.acct_id = acct.id
    #issue is here at @user
            @user.stripe_token = acct.id

  if @stripe_account.save!
        format.html { redirect_to new_bank_account_path, notice: 'Stripe account was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stripe_account }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stripe_account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**The form:**

```
  <%= form_for ([@user, @stripe_account]) do | f | %>
```

**User Model:**

```
  has_one :stripe_account
```

**Stripe_account Model:**

```
  belongs_to :users
```

the acct.id gets saved into the stripe_account table but not the user table.  The user table has a user.stripe_account record.

How can i save the acct.id in both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are only doing `@stripe_account.save` and not doing `@user.save` (why did you cut your method?).

You can add a `@user.save` or set the belongs_to assocaition with the `autosave: true` option.

I'd recommend you to change this:

```
@stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id
```

to this, though:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stripe_account = @user.build_stripe_account(stripe_account_params)
```

I don't think the autosave will works if you only set the id and not the actual object.

Comment: Well stripe_account and user are separate tables.  The user table will be first.  So once the user creates the stripe_account, i want the stripe_account (the account token which is acct.id) to be also in the User table under stripe_account..... im also not sure by cut my method, what do you mean?

Comment: and yes, i only do "if @stripe_account.save!" .. but if i do it that way, doesn't nothing get saved into the StripeAccount table? I only want the acct.id in the User table from the stripe_account form/create

Comment: With "why did you cut your method?" I meant that, why are you not showing the complete method? I had to guess you only save the stripe_account object.

Comment: I don't understand your last question, if you set the relationship as autosave, when you save the `@stripe_account` object it will also save the `@user` associated object. If you set `@user.stripe_token` before saving the stripe_account, it will also update the users table.

Comment: ok so to clarify, it will save in both places?  Because im worried without "@stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)"... will it save in both?

Comment: added the rest of the method

Comment: `@user.build_stripe_account` instantiates a new StripeAccount object, when you save that object it goes to the `stripe_accounts` table.

Comment: OH!!! it workd. thanks.  ithink at least.  if i see any issues ill update youand hopoefully you respond lol.  thank anyway and ill give you the green check shecks